# Angular "partial" vs "full" compilation mode?

Tags: angular, angular12, angular-library, angular-ivy

Why the library compiled in the "partial" compilation mode builds so slowly inside of the consumer application, compared to the "full" compilation mode?

Comment: I found the reason for this issue in my project, so it might help someone. 
To me, the problem was that I was using the kendo library, and was loading a lot of styles of some kendo components on my component level, to override it. 
After I moved the style out of the component level to the global level, the issue was resolved. It looks like the angular emulated encapsulation has some performance issues when you have a lot of the CSS on the component level.

Answer (score 7):

As the documentation states:

> `full` Generates fully AOT-compiled code according to the version of Angular that is currently being used.

> `partial` Generates code in a stable, but intermediate form suitable for a published library.

Effectively this means that the `partial` compiles more slowly compared to `full` because the `partial` compilation has to build more compatible target code than with `full`. See [this](https://blog.lacolaco.net/posts/en/angular-ivy-library-compilation-design-in-depth/) post for further details considering Ivy. Hope the next image helps you too with understanding:
[intermediate compilation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vQzt.png)